# Chain of trust and tpm?

Tags: boot, bios, tpm

[image: Chain of trust]

Lets take the 1st step when the CRTM measures the Bios it extends the hash value to the PCR located in the TPM. Before passing control to the bios it must be a verification of hash values. My question is there an agent (third party) to commit this verification? or PCRs has a default set, so each time extending hash values these values must correspond to the PCR default hash before passing the control to bios?

Answer (score 0):

It depends. In some implementations, the CRTM is a part of BIOS, so you have to implicitly trust the first boot block of BIOS to be loaded, which then verifies the rest of the BIOS. In other implementations, such as with [Intel's AMT](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-trusted-execution-technology-a-primer), the CPU measures the BIOS independently.

Answer (score 0):

What you asked is the PCR values from so-called "**golden measurement**" or "**baseline measurement**", which can be conducted by the platform manufacturer such as DELL or platform administrator like your department IT. Those values are saved and used for verification by TPM. This is part of the "**provisioning process**".

Please check the book "[TCG TPM v2.0 Provisioning Guidance](https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/wp-content/uploads/TCG-TPM-v2.0-Provisioning-Guidance-Published-v1r1.pdf)" for section 10 and section 11.